# Link List : initializing the header

Tags: java, linked-list

So I'm working on a problem to print the nth element from the last of the list.

I have the method and a procedure figured out. This procedure finds the element.

```
public Node nth_element(Node head, int n){ 
  // head to point to the first element in the list
  // n is the element to be returned from the tail of the list
  ---do the function here---
}
```

Now when I'm in the main class and calling the above method. My Linked List class where the above method is declared initializes the head to null in its constructor.

How do i initialize the head?

This is my main class:

```
  public class Main
    {

    static void main()
    {
    List l = new List() //initialize the list

    //then i add the elements into the list using insert()
    //display()

    //now 
    **Node mynode = l.nth_element(head, value);**
    // how do i initialize this head 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of class you are referring to as main class?

Comment: @hemanth made an edit in the question, you are right should have put down the class.

Answer (score 1):

In your self-defined linked list class `List`, you need to put `head` as the class field as

```
public class List {
    private Node head = null;
    // all method for List....
}
```

Then when you implement `nthElement` method, you don't have to use `head` as your first argument since it's already a class member and you can use it directly in your class methods. But if you do need to, then you can create a public method in `List` class:

```
public Node getHead() {
    return head;
}
```

Your `nthElement` method will look like

```
public Node nthElement(Node head, int n) {
    //implementation ...
}
```

Then in the main method, you can call `nthElement` like

```
Node mynode = l.nthElement(l.getHead(), value);
```

But make sure that your list is not empty. Otherwise, `head` is `null`.

Comment: if head is an instance variable why do you want to pass it as the argument to the method from the same class?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said he doesn't need to use head as the first argument of the method. But if he really wants to do in that way, then that's a workaround.

Comment: @tonga thank you for the input, i see where i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @tonga's answer.

Your class List constructor should be something like:

```
 private Node head;
 public List(Node head)
 {
     this.head = head;
 }
```

and then create your list

```
 List l = new List(new Node(1));
```